# PhoneGap JavaScript function not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I am new to PhoneGap. I can call javascript functions on index.html file but in other files javascript functions does not work. However normal javascript code works. What am I missing here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
 function MyFunction(){
       alert('Hi! This is irritating!!');
   }
```

---

```
 <button type="button" onclick="MyFunction()"> Click me </button>
```

---

This is code. I think that I have used all necessary files. I am not missing files here. I think that I am missing some code.
Edit: 
Below is the config.xml file

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.phonegap.gwm" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<name>gwmonline</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<access origin="*" />
 <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
<access origin="http://localhost" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="file:///android_asset/www/" subdomains="true" />
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without having any code to review. However can you assert the other js files are correctly included in html? E.g. `<script src="js/include.js"></script>`. Also you're waiting for PhoneGaps's equivalent call to `document.ready`?

Comment: Hi, I have added code. I have used all necessary files with code. It works on main page but why does it not work on others? And why not functions? Javascript works normally. Is there something to add ?

Comment: May I recommend you some help how to post good code examples? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your function and button for themselves look fine so my guess is just some correction in what is calling what at which time is needed. Also writing this minimal example could maybe solve your problem all together. For example for a simple alert and onclick you don't need jQuery so get rid off it for the moment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mind guys. I figured it out. It was a PhoneGap issue. In PhoneGap, We have to add all script and their references at index.html page.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how did you do that? I'm having trouble loading my JS.

Answer (score 0):

As Yoshi says, you need to make sure you're including the right javascript files in your index.html and if you're using any plugins or device specific features then make sure you're waiting for the [deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) event to fire too.

Comment: I am not using any plugins or device specific features. About deviceready event, Does it fire every time when a page gets load or only main page?

Comment: Quote from the phonegap documentation: The deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs. Applications typically attach an event listener with document.addEventListener once the HTML document's DOM has loaded.

Comment: If you're not using any plugins, then have you just tried browsing to your app from Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I did. It works just fine in chrome. But When I do it in PhoneGap, It does not work.

Comment: Is there something to add in PhoneGap? I don't think that it is javascript problem. I think that I am missing something in PhoneGap setting or whatever.

Comment: Can you post the full /www/index.html file, the /config.xml and any javascript files please?

Comment: I have edited my question. I have attached config.xml file. I am only using cordova.js file. And I am writing my javascript code in html file itself.